# Get number of rows in a BigQuery table (streaming buffer)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am doing inserts via Streaming. In the UI, I can see the following row counts:

[image]

Is there a way to get that via the API? Current when I do:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = client.dataset("bqtesting")
table = client.get_table(dataset.table('table_streaming'))
table.num_rows
0
```

Obviously 0 is not the number that I'm looking to get. From the API documentation it says:

> numRows   unsigned long   [Output-only] The number of rows of data in this table, excluding any data in the streaming buffer.

So then, my question is: how do we get the exact number of rows in a table? Currently I'm doing:

```
count=[item[0] for item in client.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bqtesting.table_streaming`').result()][0]
```

But this takes about 5s just to get the count (and I need to execute this query quite frequently to see if all streaming inserts have 'finished').

Comment: It takes some time for the row count metadata to be updated (in my experience up to 30 minutes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select count(1)` and `select count(*)` etc have 0 scanned and billed bytes (you can see this in the job metadata after you run it or in a dry run) so you should be able to run those as often as you like
if i'm reading the documentation correctly, the numbers there are not guaranteed to give you rows in the buffer which have not yet been flushed to big-query storage

you can also use the API mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability i.e. check the `streamingBuffer.oldestEntryTime` field from the `tables.get` result

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `__TABLES__` metadata table to get the information that you want. Querying `__TABLES__` incurs no charges.

The query that you need is:

```
SELECT table_id, row_count, size_bytes
FROM `your-project-name.bqtesting.__TABLES__`
WHERE STARTS_WITH(table_id, "table_streaming")
ORDER BY table_id DESC
```

Comment: this doesn't work with streaming, as it gives all zeros.

Comment: According to google pricing docs, querying these two meta tables doesn't incur charges: __PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__,  __TABLES_SUMMARY__
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing
No mention of __TABLES__ - it seems it's not free of cost.